What is the importance of the usual hypothesis assumption on the filtration?
In the study of stochastic processes, it is very common that the filtration is always assumed to be right-continuous and complete. For example, one can have a continuous/cadlag modification of a martingale or strong Markov property of a process.
In research, I wonder if there is a scenario in which assuming the usual hypothesis is too restrictive? Or is always assuming the usual hypothesis not important?
